# git clone not cloning all files

Tags: git, github, git-clone, git-fork

I am using git clone to clone a forked, private repo to my local machine:

```
git clone <url>
```

Here are the files and directories in this repo:
[image: Here are the files and directories in this repo]

However, the only files to appear in my local machine are:
[image: However, the only files to appear in my local machine are]

Clearly, it is not because they are hidden files like the majority of questions like this. The output from the clone command is as follows:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 57, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (57/57), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (43/43), done.
remote: Total 1515 (delta 15), reused 38 (delta 11), pack-reused 1458
Receiving objects: 100% (1515/1515), 9.67 MiB | 3.93 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (235/235), done.
git-lfs filter-process: git-lfs: command not found
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

And interestingly, if I do `git status`, i can see all the missing files in red and a note saying each were deleted, e.g:

```
deleted:    attention_weights/attention=0.001/[hybrid]_lycaenid-imp0.001-run1-float16.npy
deleted:    attention_weights/attention=0.001/[hybrid]_lynx-imp0.001-run1-float16.npy
```

How can I clone all these files? Why are they appearing as deleted, even though they are very much present in the fork?

Comment: It seems the repository is storing some files in git LFS. But you don't have `git-lfs` installed on your system, so those files can't be fetched.